# Python iterating through pair of values in list for function

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list like

```
cases = [(1,1), (2,2), (3,3)]
```

trying to write a function that calculates through each item and return values:

```
def case_cal(cases)
    for x, y in cases:
        result = x+y
        return result

output = case_cal(cases)
print(output)
```

I like to get output like

```
2
4
6
```

But I only get

```
2
```

I am a newbie learning python and something simple I am missing here. Could I get any advice? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `return` exits the function immediately, so you only get the the result of 1+1.

Answer (score 2):

Once you return something you move out of the function. So make a list, append your values to the list and then return in the end.

```
def case_cal(cases):
    ret_values = []
    for x, y in cases:
        result = x+y
        ret_values.append(result)
    return ret_values

output = case_cal(cases)
print(*output)
```

Comment: Your function body could also be written `return [x + y for x, y in cases]`.

Comment: @ggorlen, yes, indeed. But as the OP seems to be a beginner, didn't want to confuse him with comprehensions.

Comment: Definitely, I like this answer quite a bit.

Answer (score 2):

Your code `return`s inside the `for` loop, at the end of the first iteration, so you'll only see the first `x + y` result.

This is a perfect use for a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators), which will allow you to grab the next `x + y` calculation on demand and offer maximum control over what the caller can do with the result:

```
cases = [(1,1), (2,2), (3,3)]

def case_cal(cases):
    for x, y in cases:
        yield x + y

for x in case_cal(cases):
    print(x)
```

Output:

```
2
4
6
```

Comment: Using `list` comprehensions for side-effects is evil (it's a functional programming tool; true functional programming is naturally side-effect free, and people don't tend to expect side-effects in functional constructs even in multiparadigm languages). It also needlessly creates `list`s of `None` (minor performance cost, and in a `repl`, it means echoing out that `list` of `None` for bonus confusion). `for x in case_cal(cases): print(x)` is equally simple, and not willfully evil. :-)

Comment: I'm not sure I buy that Python has much relation to "true functional programming", but I accept the argument that it creates a list of `None` unnecessarily. Will adjust!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply map the items of the list to the `sum` function:

```
list(map(sum, cases))
```

This becomes:

```
[2, 4, 6]
```

Or if you want to print the items individually:

```
for s in map(sum, cases):
    print(s)
```

This outputs:

```
2
4
6
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont need the values in a list you can procced as follows:

```
cases = [(1,1), (2,2), (3,3)]

def case_cal(cases):
    for x, y in cases:
        result = x+y
        print(result)

case_cal(cases)
```

Just directly print the values instead of returning them as once you return something you move out of the function.
Also,

```
cases = [(1,1), (2,2), (3,3)]

def case_cal(cases):
    for x, y in cases:
        print(x+y)

case_cal(cases)
```

Comment: Writing a function that has side effects when OP is trying to write a function with no side effects seems to avoid the problem--it's fundamentally a different function.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
cases = [(1,1), (2,2), (3,3)]

def case_cal(cases):
    results = []
    for x, y in cases:
        results.append(x + y)
    return results

output = [case_cal(cases)]
print(output)
```

And then you could define a print function like this:

```
def print_cases(cases):
    for elem in cases[0]:
        print(elem)
```

But there is a more Pythonic way:

```
def case_cal(cases):
    return [(x + y) for (x, y) in cases]
```

This is called a list comprehension, and you are going to be using them very often in python. You can read more about them [here](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/lists/list-comprehensions-in-python/).

Comment: Thanks for the link on the list comprehension! Helps me to understand more about Python as I am teaching myself right now.

Answer (score 0):

Simply do the following:

```
def case_calc(cases):
    for x, y in cases:
        print(x + y)

case_calc([(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3)])
```

Cheers